# A button doesn´t do any action when extending JButton, but it does it with a method returning JButton

Tags: java, swing, inheritance, constructor, jbutton

how are you?, i have a problem that i am sure is something really stupid but i can´t figure what it is. I am trying to create a button, so every time i want to use that button that does the action that i want, all i do is create that new button that already owns the action and the resourceBundle.

my code is this:

```
public class AcceptNewTaskButton extends JButton {

 private ActionManager actionManager;
 private JButton acceptNewTaskButton;

public AcceptNewTaskButton(JDialog dialog,JDateChooser dateChooser,JTextField      textField){

    super(ResourceBundle.getBundle("Language").getString("locale_button_accept"));
    actionManager = new ActionManager(dialog,dateChooser,textField);

    acceptNewTaskButton = new   JButton(actionManager.getNewTaskAction(dialog,dateChooser,textField));


}}
```

This code doesn't do what i want, because when i code this

```
okbutton = new AcceptNewTaskButton(dialog,datechooser,newTaskName);
```

the button is created but it doesn´t perform any action.

But, on the other hand, when i code this

```
public class AcceptNewTaskButton extends JButton {

private ActionManager actionManager;
private JButton acceptNewTaskButton;

public JButton AcceptNewTaskButton(JDialog dialog,JDateChooser dateChooser,JTextField textField){


    actionManager = new ActionManager(dialog,dateChooser,textField);
    acceptNewTaskButton = new JButton(actionManager.getNewTaskAction());
    acceptNewTaskButton.setText(ResourceBundle.getBundle("Language").getString("locale_button_accept"));

    return acceptNewTaskButton;

}}
```

And i type this

```
okButton = new AcceptNewTaskButton().AcceptNewTaskButton(dialog,dateChooser,newTaskName);
```

The action is perfectly performed.

I would like to know why this is happening, i think it is something simple but i can´t see it. I would like to do it this way because i want to have a class of every button in a package called buttons, and in this way make my code more "object oriented"

Thank you so much!

pd: excuse me if i commited any grammar mistake, english isn´t my native language

Comment: What does the `Action` behind `newTaskAction` look like?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your class already extends JButton so you don't want to create a new button.

I think you should be doing:

```
// acceptNewTaskButton = new   JButton(actionManager.getNewTaskAction(dialog,dateChooser,textField));
setAction(  actionManager.getNewTaskAction(dialog,dateChooser,textField) );
```